# options of maximum number of iterations and convergence tolerance for pyoptsparse driver

Tags: openmdao

I tried the pyoptsparse driver and found it has not two useful options:

a. maximum number of iterations

b. convergence tolerance

the scipyoptimizer has these two options.

Can these two options be added in the pyoptsparse dirver?
Thank you very much.

Henry

Answer (score 1):

The thing that makes pyoptsparse tricky is that it is a wrapper around many different types of optimizers, and each one may have different options. We allow you to set these in OpenMDAO using the opt_settings dictionary. For example, you can set the tolerance in SLSQP by setting the 'ACC' key:

```
    prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
    prob.driver.opt_settings['ACC'] = 1e-9
```

To find these for your specific optimizer, you will have to look at either pyoptsparse's documentation, or just look at their source wrapper for the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Kenneth Moore's answer, the options for SLSQP can be found in the documentation here (as of February 2023): https://mdolab-pyoptsparse.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/optimizers/SLSQP.html

The other PyOptSparse optimisers are also covered on this website, just use the menu on the right of the page. Note that the options for the different optimisers are not the same.